# fullPage plugin not working properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I have 2 problems with the mobile version of the `fullPage` plugin.

1. I can't browse my page although I have everything properly included. I have similar options as on page http://bearonunicycle.com/#contact and still can't get it to work my site. When I try to swipe through the page I can't even get through the first section.
2. Scrolling on mobile devices is so hard, I need to scroll my whole screen up to 5 times to move just a bit.

My head includes the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
```

And here is initialization code.

```
$(function(){
    $('.cycle-slideshow2').each(function(){
        $.cycle2Init($(this));
    });

    $.fn.fullpage({ 
        scrollingSpeed: 250,
        verticalCentered: false,
        resize: false,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        touchSensitivity: 100,
    });
});
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to know what's the problem if you don't add code or a link to your site.

Comment: Sorry, edited. I've shown a bit of head code and initialization. Is it possible that fullPage is coliding with cycle2 plugin ?

Comment: Could you add your HTML markup? The problem might be there.

Comment: Your touch sensitivity is huge, default is 15. Use a lower value there for your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't use same classes for fullpage and cycle2. I used .slide class in cycle2 and after including fullpage that uses .slide as [default](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#initialization) class, things went mad.